# White lines flashing on screen after sleep mode

Tags: 14.04, compiz, intel-graphics, screen

I have a strange problem occurring on my laptop screen.
As soon as I have exited sleep mode a white flickering horizontal line maybe 1 or 2 pixels broad appears at the top of the screen.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 side-by-side with Windows 8 on a HP EliteBook with I5 processor and Intel 4th Gen Integrated Graphics.

Most posts I've read suggest that this is a hardware error... but it does not appear otherwise or in Windows (even after sleep mode) which I suppose would be the case if the screen was falling apart.

I have also seen and tried Compiz-workaround with "force redraw" which unfortunately had no effect.

Does anyone have a similar problem or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem with HP ProBook 650 (especial when I lock and unlock the screen in Gnome Shell). My workaround (when the line appears) is to run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..2}
do
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0
    xset dpms force suspend
    xset dpms force on
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 1
    # sleep 0.2
done
```

I call this script "reload my display". Sometimes it does not work at first time and it is why I used a `for` loop.

After that, the line disappears until next lock screen.

Comment: Hey thanks man it worked like charm. Upvoted